# Edit a paper_trail version without creating a new version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I'm using paper_trail 3.0.8 on a Rails 3.2 app and I've got a model called 'levels' and I keep versions of these levels. Each level has a from_date and a cost relating to it. Whenever someone changes the date a new version is created.

I allow people to remove old versions if they want and this works well. I would like the ability to modify an old paper_trail version and save it without creating a new version.

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_paper_trail :only => [:from_date],
    :if => Proc.new { |l|
      l.versions.count == 0 || l.versions.first.item != nil && (l.versions.first.item.from_date.nil? || l.from_date > l.versions.first.item.from_date)
    }

<snip code>
end
```

If I do the following it only updates the current level and not the version

```
level = Level.find 1
version=level.versions[1].reify
version.cost_cents = 1000
version.save
```

Is there anyway to update the cost_cents for an old version?

Also is there a way to update the from_date of an old version without creating a new version on the save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway to update the cost_cents for an old version?

Yes, but the only way I know is a bit awkward.

`PaperTrail::Version` is a normal `ActiveRecord` object, so it's easy to work with in that sense, but the data is serialized (in YAML, by default) so you'll have to de-serialize, make your change, and re-serialize.

```
v = PaperTrail::Version.last
hash = YAML.load(v.object)
hash[:my_attribute] = "my new value"
v.object = YAML.dump(hash)
v.save
```

There may be a better way to do this with ActiveRecord's automatic-serialization features (like `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization`).

PS: I see you were trying to use `reify`, which returns an instance of your model, not an instance of `PaperTrail::Version`.

Comment: This is the only solution that kinda works in 2020. Hash merging multiple attributes can create "duplicate values" for nested arrays or complex structures. This can cause some model verifications to fail. It's mind-boggling that there aren't any public API methods added to papertrail in last 5-6 years since it has been asked in several stackoverflow questions.